# How to debug jasmine karma tests with VSCode tool

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am using Visual Studio Code for writing jasmine and karma based unit test cases. I would like to know if there is a way to debug tests in vs code tool itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open the debug tab
2. Add a Chrome configuration, it'll fill out most the fields for you. For the port change it to `9876` (or whatever is specified in your `karma.conf.js`). See below.
3. Set breakpoint(s) in the code you want to debug
4. Run your the debug task which will open a chrome window to the specified port
5. Run your test command (`ng test`) and refresh the opened Chrome window if necessary

Sample configuration, they are created in a filed called `launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:9876",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```